# Multiple OWIN hosts for single Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-web-roles, self-hosting

I have Web API application which has 5+ APIs in it. But now, I want to host each of them on a different Host(Self-Hosted).

**Can we use OWIN to host multiple Web APIs on a single Azure Web Role?**